# Remove fully enclosed bottom bracket

Tags: road-bike, crankset, bottom-bracket, tools

I am in the process of replacing my worn out bottom bracket. After removing the crankset I see that there are no insets on the bottom bracket for my bottom bracket removal tool to latch on to:

[image]

According to the bike manufacturer the bottom bracket is fully enclosed as seen in the picture. I have tried prying the black cap off with a screwdriver but it wont come off. Applying more force with the screwdriver seems to damage the frame and cap as seen in the picture below. The cap seems to be made of some hard rubber type material.

[image]

How do i remove this type of bottom bracket?

Comment: I think the answer might be 'use more force'. What does the other (drive) side look like? Just out of curiosity, what is the thing attached to the drive side of the BB shell?

Comment: Alright thank you, the drive side looks the same and the thing attached on the other side is a mount for the chain / crankset shield.

Comment: Also try unscrewing it? What does the text on the BB around the axle say? What's the make/model of bike?

Comment: Since you'll be working on a bearing it would be a good idea, just as a side-note, to clean the frame thoroughly BEFORE opening the BB. Grease and grime don't marry well.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Sorry for the delay, i tried unscrewing but it didn't budge. Applying more force with the screwdriver resulted in some damage as seen in the new picture so i am affraid to use more until i know that is the proper way to remove it. The text around the axle says "Pressed version 35" aswell as the country of manufacture. It is a swedish brand "Skeppshult", i am almost certain that https://www.skeppshult.se/sv/cyklarna/man/stil-premium/ is the bike. When looking at the product spec the bottom bracket is just noted as "Bottom bracket fully encapsulated with machine bearings".

Comment: @Carel Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Looks like threads under the rubber cover? FYI the thread might be left hand

Comment: The “press” suggests it’s a press fit BB and would come out by hammering one end of the spindle, but I would first try contacting the bike manufacturer via the website you linked.

Comment: @Andrew I contacted the manufacturer and i they said to use a hammer as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the manufacturer and they said to  use a hammer from the drive side which worked perfectly.